# How can I transform a Java String from args[] to an integer

Tags: java, timer, int, args

I've got a little problem with the java Timer:

The main point is that it converts args[] to an int (which I can place in a timer-time)

My code looks just like this:

```
String bArgs = sArgument;
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(args[1].toString());
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[" + ChatColor.RED + "Werbung" + ChatColor.GOLD + "]" + ChatColor.BOLD + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + bArgs);
      }
    }, 1*minutes*1000, 1*minutes*1000);
    return true;
```

But I can't convert the args[1] to an Int that I can place this int in the timer :(

Comment: "*But I can't convert the args[1] to an Int*" do you get any error/exception/invalid result?

Comment: Gonna need a bit more info than that. Why "can't" you?

Comment: what do yu think about: Integer.paresInt()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

args[0] is the first argument :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("timer job...");             }
            }, 1*minutes*1000, 1*minutes*1000);
    }
```

Comment: If I do it like you said, there will be an error: **An Internal Error occured while attempting to perform this command**

Comment: This works for me. U need to run with argument ,ie. java MyClass 5